# Stop receiving when keyboard is hidden

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I have a custom keyboard extension and its containing app. After launching, containing app send to my extension a number every 2 seconds. I catch it and output to the text field. But I have a problem. When extension keyboard appears on a screen - it starts to receive numbers. But when it disappears it still receive numbers.

Question: how to stop receiving numbers when my extension is hidden?

Edit: I run my extension receiver in an infinite loop. How to exit this loop if keyboard is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you could check the keyboard height to see if you should be sending numbers to the keyboard using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. If it's zero, you're hidden. You can also check your overall height in the keyboard extension and decide if you should parse the data you're sending.